# M2.1: &amp;quot; in frontend product attribute dropdowns

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, frontend

One of our clients sells products that have sizes displayed as e.g. **4" x 6"**

The client has just reported that configurable products that contain the size option in a dropdown have started to be displayed as **`4&quot; x 6&quot;`**. This may or may not be related to a recent upgrade to 2.12, I can't say for certain.

The JSON that's rendered in the page for the configurable combinations is correct - **`"4&quot; x 6&quot;"`**, it has to be because the fields are delimited by quotes.

But when the string is rendered into the select box by the front end code, it is translated to **`&amp;quot;`**, hence the display issue.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a fix?